# Send both erc20 and native ether to contract on deployment

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, contract-deployment, ethers.js

I'm trying to send LINK (erc20) and Ether (goerli in this case) to my contract on deployment. I understand how to do this for native/testnet ether. But how do I combine them to send erc20 and ether at the same time, whenever I deploy my contract? I have already set approval prior to deployment for the token to spend signer's LINK

Current deployment code:

```
            let factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer);
            let contract = await factory.deploy(
                arg1,
                arg2,
                ..., 
                { 
                    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.00001")
                }
            );
```

Comment: If you already set approval then your contract can use LINKs belong to sender. Why do you need to "send" link during deployment ? "sending" here means the code in your constructor call "send" in Link Contract ? Could you clarfiy more the reason, the use case and your constructor code ?

Comment: afaik you would need a second transaction to send the tokens as is a separate contract.
Hope it helps

Comment: @minhhn2910 I ultimately need to use those tokens for using a Chainlink function (which requires LINK). And I also want the user to send an amount of Ether to the contract to pay for gas later on. As they both will require a gas fee, I was hoping that there would be a method to transfer both at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you already know how to send ethers to the contract and to send some erc20 as well during deployment, you can modify the constructor to transfer the link tokens while deployment.
The code would look something like this.

```
constructor(uint256 linkAmount){
    IERC20(0x).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), linkAmount);
    // rest of code
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That gives me the error: `execution reverted` whenever trying to deploy the contract. An example of a transaction that failed this way is: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x23ae073a5ee57a0a996492c576ee1205e751e4cd964ac62857bd0aedf50fb2d5

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, to send both Ether and an ERC20 token to a contract at deployment, you can use the `transferAndCall` function provided by the `ERC223` standard. This function allows you to send both Ether and an ERC20 token in a single transaction.
have a look at https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/677